# Anime.js how to reverse this animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, reverse, anime.js

I've recently started working with Anime.js to animate my designs and I´ve been stuck in this for a while now, bet for many this is very simple! 
I have a button that enlarges my div and would like to have the div in its initial state if the icon is clicked again.
My HTML:

```js
var boxGetsLarger = anime({
  targets: '.agent-button',
  width: {
    value: '+=300',
    duration: 200,
    easing: 'linear'
  },
  borderRadius: {
    value: 83
  },
  duration: 200,
  height: {
    value: '+=20'
  },
  easing: 'linear',
  autoplay: false

});


document.querySelector('.agent-button').onclick = boxGetsLarger.play;
```

```css
.agent-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0pt 2pt 10pt #0000001f;
  height: 91px;
  width: 91px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<div class="agent-button close">
  <img src="img/audio-bars.svg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

It is shame there is no built-in toggle function but there is a [reverse](http://animejs.com/documentation/#reverseAnim) function what this does is toggle the internal attribute `reversed` which, in turn, controls what the `play` function does.

In theory, you can just call `reverse` after `play` like so

```js
var boxGetsLarger = anime({
  targets: '.agent-button',
  width: {
    value: '+=300',
    duration: 200,
    easing: 'linear'
  },
  borderRadius: {
    value: 83
  },
  duration: 200,
  height: {
    value: '+=20'
  },
  easing: 'linear',
  autoplay: false
});

document.querySelector('.agent-button').onclick = function() {
  boxGetsLarger.play();
  boxGetsLarger.reverse();
}
```

```css
.agent-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0pt 2pt 10pt #0000001f;
  height: 91px;
  width: 91px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<div class="agent-button close">
  <img src="img/audio-bars.svg">
</div>
```

Only I found `reverse` was running before `play` was finished leading to some strange behaviour, I'd recommend taking advantage of the 'finished' promise built-in like so

```js
var boxGetsLarger = anime({
  targets: '.agent-button',
  width: {
    value: '+=300',
    duration: 200,
    easing: 'linear'
  },
  borderRadius: {
    value: 83
  },
  duration: 200,
  height: {
    value: '+=20'
  },
  easing: 'linear',
  autoplay: false
});

document.querySelector('.agent-button').onclick = function() {
  boxGetsLarger.play();
  boxGetsLarger.finished.then(() => {
    boxGetsLarger.reverse();
  })
}
```

```css
.agent-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0pt 2pt 10pt #0000001f;
  height: 91px;
  width: 91px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<div class="agent-button close">
  <img src="img/audio-bars.svg">
</div>
```

This will now only reverse the direction when `play` is finished.

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I use this to toggle anime.js animations on a single button.

To initiate reverse() the animation must have run once. You can check this by evaluating the property: 'began'. The first time your animation runs this property will be set 'true'.

```
console.log(boxGetsLarger); // began: false

document.querySelector('.agent-button').onclick = function() {

    boxGetsLarger.play();

    if (boxGetsLarger.began) {
        boxGetsLarger.reverse();
    }

   console.log(boxGetsLarger); // began: true

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was [juliangarnier/anime#577 (comment)](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/issues/577#issuecomment-573292680):

> I encountered this issue today, here is [my solution as a pen](https://codepen.io/slavanossar/pen/PoweKmP?editors=0010).
>
> I think the confusion arises from when animations are paused, and how the `reverse()` method works:
>
> 1. Non-looped animations are automatically paused when they reach the end (or beginning when reversed).
> 2. The `reverse()` method only changes the playback direction, and doesn't unpause a paused animation.
>
> Doing `reverse()` on an animation while it is in progress means it will continue to play in the opposite direction, but if the animation is at the beginning/end (i.e. paused), you will also need to do `play()` to get it started again.

*From his linked CodePen:*

```js
function toggle() {
  if (anim.began) {
    anim.reverse()
    
    if (anim.progress === 100 && anim.direction === 'reverse') {
      anim.completed = false
    }
  }

  if (anim.paused) {
    anim.play()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try: (from [docs](http://animejs.com/documentation/#reverseAnim))

```
boxGetsLarger.reverse();
```

Comment: You'd think there'd be a toggle function 

Comment: thanks! tried already but it does conflict with the other function, the one that opens the div

Answer (score 0):

I used this to toggle back and forth between an "open" state and a "closed" state.

```
  const toggle = (animation, open) => {
    if (open) {
      animation.play();
      if (animation.reversed) {
        animation.reverse();
      }
    } else {
      animation.play();
      if (!animation.reversed) {
        animation.reverse();
      }
    }
  }
```